# UIDocumentPickerViewController crashing

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm using a UIDocumentPickerViewController in my iOS, and it will sometimes crash. It's just the view controller that crashes; the app itself is fine. I noticed this in Pages as well. When it crashes during debugging, I get the following error:

```
plugin com.apple.UIKit.fileprovider.default interrupted
```

I cannot find a good way to reproduce the issue. Is there something I can do to prevent (or at least minimize) these crashes?

Comment: I also have this issue. Managed to fix it?

Comment: Apple seems to have fixed this in the latest release.

Comment: I am getting it on ios 8.3 In which version it is fixed?

Comment: That's the one. I'm not sure why you're still experiencing it. 8.4 is coming in a few weeks. Maybe hold out until then?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you are having connectivity issues that could be creating a race condition?  Try using something like FXReachability to receive notices on network status changes to see if there's a correlation.

Comment: I contacted Apple's Developer Technical Support, and they told me just to file a bug report. If I hear more, I'll update this question. I'll also look into FXReachability.

Comment: Any progress on the bug report?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't heard anything more.

Comment: It's been another month? Any more information? Did you end up finding a workaround for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After researching a lot I came to an important conclusion :

> My suggestion would be minimize the UI updation and make those changes in background so that the opening of picker is seamless.

The transition between the UI changes and displaying document picker will be smooth if you minize any UI updates.

My issue was solved after making those changes.